# Has any major corporation ever successfully sued Microsoft for intellectual property theft?

Tags: apple, software-development, software-development-kit

It is generally agreed that Microsoft stole parts if not entire blocks of intellectual property from Digital Research, Xerox, Apple, and several other major corporations.

To keep it simple, lets stipulate for MS actions prior to 1995 (Though they may have been sued for their pre-1995 actions at a later date).

**Did any major corporation ever successfully sue Microsoft for intellectual property theft?**

Comment: I have to disagree with the premise of the question. Microsoft copied ideas from other companies, but as a matter of law general ideas are not intellectual property, no matter what Apple says. Only specific implementations are protected, whether via patent or copyright.  You can protect your mousetrap, you can't protect the concept of catching mice, which is what Apple claimed.

Comment: @fluffysheap actually, I think the Apple case failed only because the relevant property had been licenced. Apple thought only for Windows 1.0 but the court found that a proper reading of the context stated otherwise. Though that's slightly academic — licencing also definitely isn't theft! Though try getting that point across next time somebody whines about Xerox and Apple.

Comment: I remember that MS has been draged to court (together with Lotus and others) in ~1988 by a New York based patent troll over Excel, as they held some spreadsheet related patent. I don't remember how that ended.

Comment: 1) Microsoft copied lots of ideas (both Microsoft and Apple got ideas from Xerox PARC, and the Xerox engineers, as I recall, were happy to show them off for someone to use since Xerox wasn't particularly interested), and innovated others.

Comment: 2) "Intellectual property" covers many disparate things, typically copyrights, trademarks, and patents. Of these, patents are public knowledge, and so can't really be stolen. Trademarks can be infringed, but not really stolen (unless they're being illegitimately used, maybe? (IANAL)). So the only thing that could really be stolen would be chunks of source code or art resources, perhaps. The framing of your question seems to be broader, though.

Comment: @Dranon: For what it's worth, "intellectual property" normally also includes trade secrets.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Fair point. Not sure why I spaced on that. Yes, trade secrets can definitely be stolen.

Comment: @Tommy: Actually, in the Xerox vs. Apple case, it was *not* licensed. Xerox's case was partly thrown out on rather strange legal grounds. Xerox mostly asked for a declaratory judgement to prevent Apple from suing Xerox (or their licensees). It was thrown out because the court (claimed it) wasn't convinced that Apple was likely to file such a case. The rest stemmed from Xerox basically wanting patent-like protection, but there being no patents on software at the time. If it were happening today, and Xerox's patent attorneys were good at all, they'd almost certainly win easily.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think you're right; Apple provided Xerox with $1m of pre-IPO stock options for an opportunity to spend a few days at PARC seeing what Xerox had been working on. Not for the right to produce derivative works. But, as you say, there was no clear legal protection on Xerox's ideas for Apple to negotiate a purchase of at the time, so it's not surprising that there was later contention. If it were happening today, I dare imagine (i) Apple would have to offer more than $1m; and (ii) would acquire licensing as part of the exchange.

Comment: @JerryCoffin no, it's even more nuanced than that. See the judgment in Xerox v Apple, https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=3538913398421433687 — "On June 9, 1981, Xerox granted Apple a license pursuant to which Apple agreed to "participate in a project with the Learning Research Group at PARC/Xerox for the purpose of implementing the Smalltalk-80 language and system on a hardware system to be developed by [Apple]." "; Apple obtained a licence but then did something slightly different, implementing something far descended from the Smalltalk-80 system but not the language.

Comment: @Tommy: While it's certainly true that Apple had *a* license, it wasn't a license to do (even close to) what they actually did. If you read through the decision, you'll find that the court did **not** base any of its decision on (even the remote possibility of) that license applying either. The decision was based on the fact that Apple hadn't sued Xerox, and Xerox hadn't shown evidence that they were likely to do so either, so it wasn't "judiciable".

Comment: @Tommy: If the pre-existing license had any effect at all, it was in preventing Xerox from filing a stronger case to start with. Personally, I rather doubt that though. The real problem at the time was from the patent office rejecting patents on everything related to software, so rights holders were stuck trying to use copyright law to cover "look and feel" issues, which didn't fit with copyright law. Some others (e.g., Lotus) had successfully applied copyright law to look and feel, but legally that was pretty questionable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin for you to argue not 'even close to' we must disagree on the distinction between the Smalltalk-80 system and the Smalltalk-80 language: Xerox seems to consider the former to be the totality of the user environment. If the Lisa/Mac is not 'even close to' the Xerox user environment, the rest of the discussion is moot. I'm sticking with 'slightly different' for being 'far descended' but ignoring the language. And the discussion started from "licencing also definitely isn't theft" so the existence of a licence is relevant regardless of the grounds on which that case was decided.

Comment: @Tommy: You're misunderstanding: the "not even close to" was that the license was basically for Apple to form a joint venture with Xerox, where Apple was going to develop the hardware, and Xerox would port Smalltalk to it. It was not at all for Apple to simply develop something on their own, regardless of how similar it might be to all or part of Smalltalk.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't see any indication of who was expected to produce software, only that Apple would produce hardware and that the whole project would be collaborative. Collaborating with a research team often means merely absorbing their research, so the idea that there was an intention that Xerox would port Smalltalk is conjecture. But I think we're well down an alley on this. Grab the last word if you want it; it's my fault that we are where we are, but I think I've created a discussion that isn't very relevant.

Comment: Microsoft steal from xerox? Wasn't it MS stealing from Apple which stole from Xerox?

Comment: Apple had a much stronger case that Microsoft stole code from QuickTime for Windows than the look and feel case that Apple lost. Microsoft agreed to write Mac Office for 5 years and paid Apple $150m in 1997 to make the QuickTime lawsuit go away https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Canyon_Company

Comment: DEC sued Microsoft on the grounds that Cutler took Mica code with him when he joined MS, and some of that code turned up in Windows NT (presumably transcribed from Pillar to C). MS settled out of court, including agreeing to support NT on Alpha.  https://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/death-alpha-nt

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Alcatel-Lucent* won a lawsuit against MS in 2008 on a patent for audio file playback. That was later overruled by a higher court.

*Bristol Technology* attacked MS for not revealing needed Windows sources and entering other markets. MS was charged to pay $1M to Bristol in 2000.

*Spyglass*, the company that originally built what is Internet Explorer today, filed a case against MS on the basis that MS was giving their product away for free after they licensed it from them, inhibiting them from making any money and won $8M (which I would consider a ridiculously low sum today - apparently, internet wasn't considered important by that court at that time).

*Stac* was already mentioned in another answer

*Sun Microsystems* were successful in court in forcing MS stop shipping their own "MS standard" Java VM, probably the only company that successfully attacked MS's traditional way of working with open industry standards (pretend to adopt, change in an incompatible way, take over, make your own version).

There were numerous lawsuits other than that in MS history, obviously. MS policy has apparently always been to settle such lawsuits in private agreements outside court.

Most of those (except the first, which MS won in the long run) were not directly on **theft** of IP, but rather improper **usage** of IP or "predatory business practices". I personally think IP theft is *so hard to prove*, (especially has been in the early days, and see SCO vs. Linux) that lawyers will likely revert to other means to get at someone if they can. Most of the accusals of IP theft MS decided to settle outside court, probably to cover the details.

Comment: MS was publicly shy about law suits until about the year 2000 & NT. The theory was MS was afraid a company would make a precedence setting case that DOS was stolen and they had no legal rights (the legal term is called "fruit of the poison tree") - but it was just a theory.

Comment: You've characterized the Sun vs. MS lawsuit almost exactly the opposite of reality. Microsoft didn't make any incompatible changes at all--Sun was the one that made a change that wasn't backward compatible. The lawsuit was only over the terms of the contract. The court ruled that the contract allowed Sun to make any such changes they wanted, as often as they wanted, and require Microsoft to follow them or quit shipping a JVM. In short, no matter how hard Microsoft might try to follow the contract, Sun was in a position to prevent them from doing so.

Comment: At the time, Sun was also allowing other JVM licensees to continue shipping their implementations of the older standard, just like Microsoft was doing, so it was *fairly* clearly a direct attack on Microsoft, not just trying to enforce following the new standard. In short, far from being "Microsoft doing bad things", this was Sun using Microsoft to popularize Java, then when that worked, turning around and stabbing their former partner in the back.

Comment: @jwzumwalt: In a former life I got a chance to talk to some of Microsoft's lawyers about such things. They were pretty clear about the reason: they knew it would be *very* easy for them to be perceived as bullies, so they were only willing to initiate lawsuits in cases where it was *extremely* obvious that they were being wronged. Oh, and this was after 2000 too.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Answers on this probably depend on whom you ask: "*According to Sun, the version of Java distributed by Microsoft worked better with its Windows software. Such a move threatened Java's ability to provide a cross-platform development environment, Sun's lawyers said.*" I couldn't find any hints that Sun were the bad guys in that controversy except yours - But it's not me to judge, that's what jurisdiction is good for.

Comment: @tofro: Think about what you just quoted for a moment. This really translates to Sun saying: "Microsoft wrote a better JVM than ours, so Java on Windows worked better than Java on other platforms." (Oh, and yeah, that's exactly how it was, too). I had the joy of testing the "wrote once, run anywhere" motto a bit early on. Getting an applet to work on just three OSes (Solaris, Windows, and Mac OS) made porting C code seem like a breeze by comparison.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If you think building proprietary extensions for one platform into a system that is intended for multi-platform deployment is a good thing, you probably should be re-thinking your understanding of exactly that. Because such stuff creates an even worse situation than the one you describe in your last sentence.

Comment: @tofro: That't not what I said, and it's not what happened either. Much of what happened is that Microsoft optimized their JVM so Java ran faster on a cheap x86 than it did on a much more expensive SPARC. Microsoft *did* also use Sun's own mechanism for connecting the JVM to the rest of the system--in particular, they created a generic "connector" to allow transparent use of COM. All done exactly by Sun's rules. Sun used the same thing to accomplish roughly the same ends--Microsoft just did it a lot better than Sun had even attempted to.

Comment: The real reason Sun was angry came down to one thing: Sun *thought* they'd rigged the game so they could win. Then Microsoft came in and played Sun's game by Sun's rules--and even then, made Sun's work look utterly sad by comparison.

Comment: Case of U.S. (**not** Sun) against MS: "In short, Microsoft feared and sought to impede the development of network effects that cross-platform technology like Netscape Navigator and Java might enjoy and use to challenge Microsoft's monopoly. Another internal Microsoft document indicates that the plan was not simply to blunt Java/browser cross-platform momentum, but to destroy the cross-platform threat entirely, with the "Strategic Objective" described as to "Kill cross-platform Java by grow[ing] the polluted Java market.]". Doesn't sound like "play Sun's game by Sun's rules" to me

Comment: @tofro: You're mistaking the end for the means. No, what they wanted to accomplish wasn't at all in accord with Sun's wishes (just as what Sun wanted to accomplish wasn't in accord with Microsoft's wishes). But as far as the contract with Sun goes, all evidence is that Microsoft intended to follow the contract, and thought they were doing so (and had actually done so, right up until Sun changed the rules).

Comment: At least as far as I know, the US anti-trust suit never alleged anything about violating the contract with Sun--it was all about things like "tying" Internet Explorer to Windows.

Comment: "pretend to adopt, change in an incompatible way, take over, make your own version" - This is usually referred to as EEE (Embrace, Extend, Extinguish).

Answer (score 16):

Stac Electronics obtained [a 1994 judgment against Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20070509205650/http://www.vaxxine.com/lawyers/articles/stac.html) for patent infringement, based on Microsoft's use of knowledge it had learnt from Stac's source code for Stacker, which it had obtained while considering a purchase of the company, during implementation of DoubleSpace.

Microsoft filed an appeal but Stac one-upped them with a successful injunction on sales of affected copies of DOS, so Microsoft ended up settling. So Stac's action was a success.

Stac had IPOd in 1992, selling 3 million shares at ["a a respectable"](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/teslas-future-10-post-ipo-disasters/) $12/share (though it quickly dropped). Given Stacker's profile at the time and the respectable IPO, I would argue that the company meets the appropriate definition of a 'major corporation', albeit that it wasn't a Xerox or Apple as I'm willing to wager that's more value than was contemporaneously assigned to Digital Research.

Comment: Good point. I had forgotten about this. When I ask the question, it seemed to me somebody successfully sued MS for some type of audio technology too. I remember MS hiring employees from other companies that may have brought illegal software with them, but I can't remember any specific cases - perhaps Borland and one or more of their compilers as an example.

Comment: Didn’t MS pay the fine / damages the a few days later bought the company anyway...

Comment: I can't find a reliable (i.e. not Wikipedia) source for what happened next, but Wikipedia thinks Stac used the payment and subsequent royalties to try to move into remote desktop access, spun off a chip subsidiary and took a shot at providing more general remote support software, then eventually realised that things weren't going well so sold the assets and returned the resulting money to its shareholders, much like Michael Dell once advised Apple.

Comment: @jwzumwalt I think it stuck in the memory only due to the abrupt renaming of DoubleSpace as DriveSpace.

Comment: Based on what I recall, the patent infringement was related to a defragging like operation, not the initial compression of files. The compression algorithm is based on [Lempel-Ziv's 1977 "moving window" compression scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77). The patent doesn't change the original scheme, and only covers specifics like the hashing used to speed up searches for prior strings in the moving window and the Huffman tree used to encode the compressed data. Microsoft released MSDOS 6.22 with a minor change sufficient enough to not violate the specifics of the patent.